# How to perform swap function on RealmResults

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {

    RealmList<Note> results = new RealmList<>();
    results.addAll(mNotes.subList(0, mNotes.size()));

    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(results, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(results, i, i - 1);
        }
    }

    mNotes = results.where().findAll();
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}
```

I want to perform a swap function to re-arrange the order of items in the adapter.Basically I am dealing with a list on items and on drag and drop I want to rearrange the order.What I did is I copied values from RealmResults mNotes to RealmList results and done swap.How to put it back to the Realm database?

**mNotes = results.where().findAll();**
this line of code is not possible since the RealmList is not in managed mode.

Comment: I sure hope you have a field that corresponds to the position of the item.

Comment: @sreejith `RealmResults` elements cannot be swapped directly. As @EpicPandaForce suggests, I think you need extra field (let's call it `position`). You can sort the `RealmResults` using that field, and swapping to object is then done by swapping the values of the `position` field.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments.Based on your suggestion I tried sort method like this  mNotes.sort(new Comparator<Note>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Note o1, Note o2) {
                        return results.indexOf(o1.getId()) - results.indexOf(o2.getId());
                    }
                }); But this is only for api 24 .Using this for android.And Collection.sort method can not be done for realmResults !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to copy your un-managed collection using

[copyToRealmOrUpdate](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-java.lang.Iterable-) method:

```
// Initialize Realm
Realm.init(context);
// Get a Realm instance for this thread
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(results);
```

Comment: Not Working for me! .I am using the RealmResults<Note> mNotes = realm.where(Note.class).findAll(); for the RecyclerViewAdapter. Since swapping cannot be done directly to RealmResults I am converting that to RealmList and perform the swap.After swap I need to put it back to RealmResults in my case mNotes. –